# C# Library or API for upload an image of a face and have it map automatically into selected video

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am developing an application which lets a user to select a video from a list of available videos and upload an image of his/her face. Once the user has uploaded the image I need to integrate it with the video by replacing the face of the characters in the video.

The [Oddcast 3D VideoStar](http://www.oddcast.com/widgets/videostar/)
is a solution but its too costly. Is there any other `API` or `Library` available?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend two free APIs:

Related to Video editing I used: [AForgeNET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/)

Related to Face recognition/detection: [Accord](http://accord-framework.net/)

Comment: with this 2 api is it possible?

Comment: Any luck with this ?